# Can Custom Element names contain Unicode?

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element

Surprisingly can't find this on google...

Can the name of a custom element (a la the Web Components set of W3C specs) contain unicode?

This [HTML 5 Custom element names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314918/html-5-custom-element-names) says that a custom element name must begin with an ASCII character, contain a hyphen, and ANY OTHER characters. Does that mean unicode?

Comment: surprisingly underrated question

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** This [great article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) explains what characters are permitted in javascript. Unfortunately, those won’t work as expected with *elements*. At least, at the moment.

---

The reason is that `document.registerElement` which is being called on newly created custom elements, will fail:

```
var a = document.registerElement('a-ℵ');
//⇒ Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 
//    'registerElement' on 'Document': 
//    Registration failed for type 'a-ℵ'. 
//    The type name is invalid.
```

That’s because `registerElement` tries to create internal constructor, different from generic `function HTMLElement()`/`function HTMLUnknownElement()` for *registered* elements:

```
console.log(document.registerElement('a-b'));
//⇒ function a-b() { [native code] }
```

I would suggest the internals of browsers are not yet ready for:

```
//⇒ function a-ℵ() { [native code] }
```

though you might easily specify:

```
var ℵ = function() { console.log('IT WORKS') };
ℵ();
//⇒ IT WORKS
```

I understand this is not exactly an answer you expected, but I hope it sheds some light.