# ember angle-bracket syntax for non-top-level component?

Tags: ember.js

I decided to try out the angle-bracket component syntax in the canary build of ember. If create a component with `ember g component foo/bar/my-panel --pod`, how do I refer to it in a template using angle-bracket syntax?

**EDIT** Just found that `<foo.bar.my-panel />` works. Hmm... is that element syntax going to work well in browsers? Is there an alternative if not?

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20316213/2482265 on a different question custom html5 elements are valid if they start with an ascii letter and contain a hypen. Ember 2.0 also ends support for ie8 so I'd test ie9 and see what happens.

Comment: I was also worried about css, jquery, etc -- how to differentiate between element `foo.bar.my-panel` and element `foo` with classes `bar` and `my-panel`?

Comment: Jquery you can use \\ as escape see https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: Use a single \ in CSS http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier - the other thing you could do is use `classNames="..."`and use one class per component and then style it that way in css and select it that way in jquery

Comment: @Knightsy -- thanks! That takes care of my concerns, I think. If you put that all into an answer I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<foo.bar.my-panel />` is perfectly valid HTML 5 syntax. As https://stackoverflow.com/a/20316213/2482265 points out, custom HTML 5 elements are valid if they start with an ascii letter and contain a hyphen.

In order to select an element such as this in Jquery you would need to use double backslash `\\` to escape the dot `.` - see https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/ i.e.

```
$('foo\\.bar\\.my-panel')
```

For CSS you can use a single backslash `\` to escape the dot `.` - see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Finally, I myself would add a simpler className to my component such as `foo-bar-my-panel` to save the faff of selecting that way in Jquery i.e.

```
$('.foo-bar-my-panel')
```